# Right choice of Delphi Programing

Tags: macos, delphi, future

I am going to get started of Delphi Programming Language and I don't know about its future prospectus so guide me in a right way and give me some reference books for Delphi. I am also interested in Mac OS Programming is it possible..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about recommondation of literature

Comment: @jaysean - I have been using Delphi since its start: 1995. It is a wonderfully productive language/IDE-have yet to encounter better although I've worked in several languages and **many** IDE's, including C#,Python, and C++. But if you plan on working in the USA, the demand for Delphi developers is very low. The C family has always been dominant here, Pascal somewhat looked down upon. But in Europe, I think Delphi is still popular. Pascal came from Europe, C is American bred.

Comment: For MacOS you may consider CodeTyphon/Lazarus or less Delphi-like Oxygene. Judging by XE2->XE3->XE4 evolution, i would not hae high hopes about good quality FMX on MacOS and iOS

Comment: One of well-praised books is Delphi Foundation series by Chris Roliston

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Introducing Delphi Programming: Theory through Practice"
is a good Reference book and You can do it both Windows and MAC Programming in Delphi
use RAD Studio As IDE so, enjoy Delphi...

Comment: your welcome and just go through step by step not in quick overview, it is very beneficial for your future...